# Converting CURL Command to Python 2.7

Tags: python, curl, base64, python-requests

I have a curl command that works perfectly fine and gives me a HTTP 200.

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: Basic jadkfhjkafDSKJ12DD=" http://<ip>/LoadTest/rest/authentication-point/authenticate
```

The above API needs the authorization in `base64` format and the details have to be passed as Headers. This is a GET request.

When I try to run the same in Python 2.7, I get `Response [403]`. Code below.

```
import requests
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic jadkfhjkafDSKJ12DD='}
authurl = "http://<ip>/LoadTest/rest/authentication-point/authenticate"
r = requests.get(authurl, headers=headers)
print r.status_code
```

What am I missing here? How should i pass the authorization values exactly like I passed in the curl command? I've tried multiple ways but still end up getting HTTP 403 always. Kindly guide.

Comment: Wouldn't the easiest way to solve this to be capturing the network traffic and seeing what's different in your calls?

Comment: sure, How can I do that ? please suggest

Comment: Did you try using google?

Comment: May be one of these pitfalls (from http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/): 1. Authorization headers set with headers= will be overridden if credentials are specified in .netrc, which in turn will be overridden by the auth= parameter.
2. Authorization headers will be removed if you get redirected off-host.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Tim. After i made a few changes and add `session = requests.Session()`
`session.trust_env = False`, i get HTTP 500 now

Comment: Finally it worked, added the solution. Thanks all for your inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your inputs. This is the final solution. I found that there is proxy that is stopping the payload. So added the session to the request.

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
session.trust_env = False
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic jadkfhjkafDSKJ12DD='}
authurl = "http://<ip>/LoadTest/rest/authentication-point/authenticate"
r = session.get(authurl, headers=headers)
print r.status_code
```

Setting the `trust_env=False` ignores the following:

- Authentication information from .netrc (code)
- CA bundles defined in
  REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE or CURL_CA_BUNDLE (code)